# Access first item in an array decoded from an API

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api, swiftui

Hello everybody and Happy Holiday!

I am a SwiftUI novice just starting out and playing with APIs. I managed to get used to decoding API but I encounter an issue when I try to access the first item in the array. I am using SwiftyJSON to decode. I tried accessing the index 0 but the build fails with Error: Index Out of Range

Any tip would be extremely helpful especially for a novice like me.

Thank you in advance!

Model

```
struct  dataType: Identifiable {

var id: String
var title: String
var desc: String
var url: String
var image: String
```

Decoding the JSON

```
class getData: ObservableObject {

@Published var datas = [dataType]()

init() {

    let source = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=ro&apiKey=c602e42864e148dea1144f1f55255888"

    let url = URL(string: source)!

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in

        if err != nil {

            print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }

        let json = try! JSON(data: data!)

        for i in json["articles"]{

            let title = i.1["title"].stringValue
            let description = i.1["description"].stringValue
            let url = i.1["url"].stringValue
            let image = i.1["urlToImage"].stringValue
            let id = i.1["publishedAt"].stringValue

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.datas.append(dataType(id: id, title: title, desc: description, url: url, image: image))
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And finally, the view

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var list = getData()
var body: some View {

    VStack {

        WebImage(url: URL(string: list.datas[0].title), options: .highPriority, context: nil)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width:400, height:250)

        NavigationView {

                List(list.datas){i in

                    NavigationLink(destination: webView(url: i.url).navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline))
                    {
                        HStack {

                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {

                                Text(i.title).fontWeight(.heavy)

                                Text(i.desc)
                                    .lineLimit(3)
                            }

                            if i.image != "" {

                                WebImage(url: URL(string:i.image), options: .highPriority, context: nil)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 110, height: 135)
                                    .cornerRadius(20)
                            }

                        }.padding(.vertical, 15)
                    }

                }.navigationBarTitle("Noutati")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`URLSession` executes `dataTask` asynchronously, so at the start there is no data yet, ie. `datas` is empty, so trying to get first (below `datas[0]`) element of empty array result in exception (which you see)

```
WebImage(url: URL(string: list.datas[0].title), options: .highPriority, context: nil)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width:400, height:250)
```

instead you need to show some stub view till data got loaded, like below

```
if list.data.isEmpty {
   Text("Loading...")
} else {
    WebImage(url: URL(string: list.datas[0].title), options: .highPriority, context: nil)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width:400, height:250)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works wonderfully. Any tip on how can access any other index? It works just fine with the first item but anything above 0 will return Error: Index out of range.

Comment: I've managed to solve this by adding if datas.count < 3 show index of 2 and so on. Thank you once again for your help!